# Display product thumbnail in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails, checkout

I am using Woocommerce and need to display the product thumbnails in the checkout table. I found this function:

```
function isa_woo_cart_attributes($cart_item, $cart_item_key){ 
global $product; 
if (is_cart()){ echo "<style>#checkout_thumbnail{display:none;}</style>"; } 
$item_data = $cart_item_key['data']; 
$post = get_post($item_data->id); 
$thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($item_data->id, array( 80, 80)); 
echo '<div id="checkout_thumbnail" style="float: left; padding-right: 10px">' . $thumb . '</div> ' . $post->post_title; } add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', isa_woo_cart_attributes, 10, 2);
```

and this is working, but I also need to display product attributes(or alternatively product excerpt, but preferably attributes) on cart and cehckout table. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What other information do you need to display?

Comment: Ideal would be product attributes, I found a plugin for this called Woocommerce SHow Attributes, and it works when NOT using the code above for the image display, it seems like there is conflicting code when wanting to display both, image AND attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** There are some errors and mistakes in your code.

> In checkout, the cart item quantity comes after the product name… So to display correctly the product description, additional code is required.

Try the following instead:

```
// cart and checkout inline styles
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_inline_styles', 900 );
function custom_inline_styles(){
    if ( is_checkout() || is_cart() ){
        ?><style>
        .product-item-thumbnail { float:left; padding-right:10px;}
        .product-item-thumbnail img { margin: 0 !important;}
        dt.variation-Description { display: none;}
        </style><?php
    }
}

// Product thumbnail in checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'product_thumbnail_in_checkout', 20, 3 );
function product_thumbnail_in_checkout( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    if ( is_checkout() )
    {
        $thumbnail   = $cart_item['data']->get_image(array( 80, 80));
        $image_html  = '<div class="product-item-thumbnail">'.$thumbnail.'</div> ';

        $product_name = $image_html . $product_name;
    }
    return $product_name;
}

// Cart item qquantity in checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'filter_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 20, 3 );
function filter_checkout_cart_item_quantity( $quantity_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    return ' <strong class="product-quantity">' . sprintf( '&times; %s', $cart_item['quantity'] ) . '</strong><br clear="all">';
}

// Product description in cart and checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'product_descrition_to_cart_items', 20, 2 );
function product_descrition_to_cart_items( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ){
    if( $cart_item['data']->get_description() && ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) ){
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => __("Description"),
            'value' => $cart_item['data']->get_description(),
        );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**ON CART PAGE:**

[image]

**ON CHECKOUT PAGE:**

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I also want to display either product description(not SHORT description) or attributes alsong with the image in both cart and checkout(and ideally emails...)

Comment: could ther be an  error in your code? I cannot save it in my functions, it shows there is an error? I cannot save it as a php.file in Notepad+ either.

Comment: can't save the function again...sorry! But when you are saying the description can't be displayed on the cart page, could attributes or short escription be displayed ther and on checkout along with the thumbnail? I really just need to have 1-2 sentences additional info about the product in the cart and chekout table.

Comment: in my case the word "Description" is added and the text has a large left margin, see this screenshot: https://postimg.cc/image/ehl0to6jb/

Comment: Can I remove the word description and the colon?